# Validate ReCaptcha when g-recaptcha-response is resolved

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, recaptcha

I need to solve ReCaptcha and send form, but website is blocking any kind of submit until the checkbox is marked as resolved (adding class `recaptcha-checkbox-checked` and changing `aria-checked` to true does not work).

So my question is if I have `g-recaptcha-response` token can I somehow make it appear as resolved?

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: you need to hover over it and click it